# a program that get 10 numbers and print them in reverse order

Tags: c#, printing, numbers, reverse

I'm trying to write a program that takes 10 inputs and prints them in reverse order. Here is my code in c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace inverse
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i ;
        int[] n = new int[10];
        Console.WriteLine("please enter 10 numbers");
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            n[i] =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (i = 10; i >= 1; i--)
        Console.WriteLine(n[i] + " ");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't get any errors but it also doesn't work when i'm trying to debug it. Could you please help me?

---

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Do you not get prompted? Do they print, but out of sequence?

Comment: Please never say "it doesn't work" on stackoverflow.  That's not a description of a problem.  Explain precisely what you expected to happen, and precisely what happens instead.  There is an error, ***say it.*** Also, "it doesn't work when i'm trying to debug it" does not make sense.  We debug things precisely because they don't work.  Perhaps you are confused about what the term "debugging" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your second for loop to:

```
for (i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
```

Why?

Because in you incorrect for loop, `i` starts at 10. In each iteration, it decrements, until `i >= 1`. In other words, `i`'s value changes from 10 to 1.

But that's not how arrays work, is it? Arrays in C# are 0-based, meaning that the first item is at index 0, and the last item is at index (length - 1). In this specific case, the last item would be at index 9 (10 - 1 = 9)!

When you try to access the item at index 10, of course it throws an exception because the array ends at index 9! Also, even if it has an item at index 10, the first item of the array would not be printed because the loop stops at `i = 1`.

That is why you want `i`'s value to go from 9 to 0 instead of 10 to 1.

EDIT:

I just realized you made another mistake, your first for loop is incorrect as well. It should loop from 0 to 9, not 1 to 10. This is the correct version:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= 9, i++)
```

Alternatively, instead of changing the loop's headers, you can just add `- 1`:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    n[i - 1] =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (i = 10; i >= 1; i--)
    Console.WriteLine(n[i - 1] + " ");
```

Comment: I guess, in maximum programming languages array starts from 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start from 0 to 9 and vice versa

```
 for (i = 0; i <= 9 i++)
        n[i] =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 for (i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
        Console.WriteLine(n[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i;
    int[] n = new int[11];
    Console.WriteLine("please enter 10 numbers");
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        n[i] = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
    for (i = 10; i >= 1; i--)
    Console.WriteLine(n[i] + " ");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The problem was array index was out of range as the array starts from 0. It gave me error when I gave up to 10 inputs.